# Throttling Logic to control the rate of SQS messages consumption in SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have created a SpringBoot application interacting with AWS SQS.
I am consuming messages from queue(SQS) using annotation as below:

```
@SqsListener(value = "${QUEUE_Name}", deletionPolicy =SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void performVirusCheck(String request) {
        logger.debug("ENTRY-->performVirusCheck");
        migrationFPUService.virusCheckService(request);
        logger.debug("EXIT-->performVirusCheck");
    }
```

AWS credentials and other configurations are kept in 'aplication.properties' file.

The requirement is to control the rate of messages on this queueListener. Please give your suggestions on the ways to implement the above requirement.

Comment: by 'rate of messages', do you mean count of messages per polling?

Comment: This doesn't really seem to make sense, as written.  It sounds like you actually have a *different* problem (which you have not mentioned) but you have decided that the solution is to rate limit the listener, and now you are asking us how to implement your attempted solution, rather than how to solve the original problem.  We call this an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Can you add code on how this method, `performVirusCheck`, is triggered?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573196/rate-limiting-and-throttling-in-java/57586079#57586079. See if it helps