# rate limiting and throttling in java

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, throttling, rate-limiting

I need to implement ratelimiter/throttling in one of my microservice.
For example I have one User microservice that handles login and get user data based on role like Admin or normal user that is implemented using
JWT token and annotation @Secured, So, My ask is to throttle based on these what api is being called.And, I should be able to modify the throttle limit at runtime too.
I don't want to re-invent the wheel, so, any ideas please?
technology stack:- java, spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this surely depends on what you relate throttling to.

1. If you are thinking to throttle data returned by api based on role for some time, you could achieve this simply by using spring-boot cache. You can control cache evict time in springboot-app (Even if you want to externalize configuration).

Please have a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/. Also, have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfZxXGjXVfc demonstration if required.

I am not putting details of how caching is done as it's very well explained in springboot docs. So, might have to tune it according to your need but this is first answer to your controlled throttling.

2. If you are thinking to throttle the api endpoint itself or throttle the amount of data it could serve i.e. control no. of requests it could serve in a seconds etc. Then you could use `RateLimiter` from Guava.

Also, I managed to find another one probably more relevant if you are using springboot. It's [weddini/spring-boot-throttling](https://github.com/weddini/spring-boot-throttling)

Seems like 2nd approach fits more into what you need.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes, I want to throttle api in microservice , I have 3-4 endpoints and I want to have throttle for each one of them, I will explore library and see it is feasible.

Comment: Sure! Please do share. There must be some blogs using weddini

Comment: can you share whether you got answer or not?

Comment: still we are evaluating library for throttling may be to use some open source one, any pointers?Our requirement is to have throttle for every url in microservice, may be we can use tomcat valve for that any thoughts.

Comment: Guava -  is adding more latency to request any idea why?

Comment: Why can't we use spring cloud gateway here, we can use request rate limiter with that. For throttling only specific routes we can define predicates.

Comment: @RahulSingh do either of Guava or weddini support modifying api rate limits at runtime?

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented a rate limiter base on token-bucket.Other releated technology is spring-boot,spring-data-redis and lua.
Hope it can be helpful.

https://github.com/AllstarVirgo/rateLimit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).